# Delphi interaction with webpage

Tags: html, delphi, chromium

I am generating a webpage (HTML5) from Delphi (writing HTML code, saving in a temp file then open it with chromium embedded). I need to obtain the div id of the clicked element in the chromium browser.

Can this be achieved?

Code would be something like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>App title</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1 maximum-scale=1" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page" id="index">
                    <header data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
                        <h1>App header</h1>
                    </header>
                    <div data-role="content">
                        <img src="images/logo.png" />
                        <b>Autenticate</b>
                        <form method="POST" action="thelogin.php">
                            Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
                            Pasword: <input type="password" name="passw"><br>
                            <input type="submit" value="Login" data-inline="true" data-icon="gear">
                        </form>
                    </div>

                    <footer data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
                        <h1>by me</h1>
                    </footer>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is just an example. The HTML can contain also Sliders, DatePickers, TextArea, Select menus and so on...

[image]

Comment: Probably yes, but showing your HTML code would help ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Never mind. I found my solution.
It is saving the ID's of all elements added at runtime to a temporary table, then check the clicked element using:

```
frame.VisitDomProc(OnExploreDOM);
```

in onLoadEnd of the chromium. And parsing the table for all added elements to see the element with which ID was clicked.

Thanks anyway.

Comment: If you add just a tiny bit more code so something new to this problem can reproduce, that would be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this can be achieved. Your browser has a built-in DOM which you can access through JavaScript.

I'm not into JavaScript, but this code might get you started: [onclick Event click Javascript DOM Tutorial](http://www.developphp.com/view_lesson.php?v=804)

Comment: Can you exemplify please?

Comment: So... I was looking for a way to receive a notification from chromium when an element is clicked in the chromium (embedded) browser. No matter what element get's clicked. So how do I use this javascript in order to see the result in DELPHI?

Comment: Also, as I said before I will be generating HTML in runtime. So the user will choose to add a "Select menu" on the page. My app, generates the HTML for the "Select menu", adds it to the HTML file, saves it as temp.html and opens it in chromium embedded. I have no control over the ID that the user will choose for the "Select menu".

Comment: But in the end I want the user to be able to click inside Chromium on the "Select menu" that he added before, and my app should show him the properties of the clicked "Select menu" so that the user can modify them and save them so he can see the result of his changes in chromium. So it's something like a HTML5 builder. I need to be able to know which element was clicked so I can parse the HTML code and retrieve the properties and show them to the user.

Comment: Please look at the question. I added a picture of what I want to achieve

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question. Thanks for making it more clear. Upvoted.